# Show/Hide the Image and Youtube Video based on Cookie

Tags: html, jquery, cookies

In my web application initially showing Image with overlapping the video when the user click on it the form will show up after submitting the form storing the value in cookie for One day. If cookie have value the **YouTube** video will show. So that user can watch this is the functionality we have.

The functionality are working but the video are not showing if cookies have value. For this I tried below code.

Here I have submitting the code If cookie have value replacing the **YouTube** video. It's not working for me. Please suggest us where I went wrong.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Set Cookies</title>


    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">

        /* The Modal (background) */
        .modal {
            display: none; /* Hidden by default */
            position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
            z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
            padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
            left: 0;
            top: -60px;
            width: 100%; /* Full width */
            height: 100%; /* Full height */
            overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
            background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
        }

        /* Modal Content */
        .modal-content {
            background-color: #f7f7f7;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #888;
            max-width: 340px;
        }

        /* The Close Button */
        .close {
            color: #aaaaaa;
            float: right;
            font-size: 28px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .close:hover,
        .close:focus {
            color: #000;
            text-decoration: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .modal{
            padding-left: 35px;
            padding-right: 35px;
        }

        #contactform input,select {
            height: 40px;
            border: 1px solid #C6C6C6;
            color: #000;
            margin: 5px 0 0;
        }

        .errorMessage{
            color: #d13800;
            font-size: 12px;
            display: none;
        }

        .customButton{
            background-color: #0095eb !important;
            color: #fff !important;
        }

    </style>
    <style type="text/css">

        .youTypeLink{
            display: none;
        }

        .thumb {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            list-style: none;
        }

        .thumb li {
            width: 193px;
        }

        .thumb li ~ li {
            margin-left: 20px;
        }

        .thumb .thumbCaption {
            padding: 10px 0;
        }

        .overlay {
            position: relative;
        }

        .overlay .thumbnail {
            display: block;
        }

        .overlay .time {
            position: absolute; z-index: 2;
            right: 3px; bottom: 3px;
            padding: 2px 5px;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
            color: white;
        }

        .overlay .playWrapper {
            opacity: 0;
            position: absolute; z-index: 1;
            top: 0;
            width: 192px; height: 109px;
            background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6) url("http://wptf.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/play-button.png") no-repeat scroll center center / 50px 50px;
        }

        .playWrapper .playBtn {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 2;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            margin: auto; /* center */
        }

        .thumb .overlay:hover .playWrapper {
            opacity: 1;
        }


    </style>
    <script>


        function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
            let d = new Date();
            d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
            let expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
            document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
        }

        function getCookie(cname) {
            let name = cname + "=";
            let decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
            let ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
            for(let i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                let c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') {
                    c = c.substring(1);
                }
                if (c.indexOf(name) === 0) {
                    return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                }
            }
            return "";
        }

        let user = getCookie("username");
        if (user !== "") {
            $('#youTubeImage').css({"display":"none !important"});
            $('#youTypeLink').css({"display":"initial !important"});

            /* player = new YT.Player('player', {
                 width : '320',
                 height : '180',
                 videoId : 'qlEUrEVqDbo',
                 playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1 },
                 events : {
                     'onReady' : onPlayerReady,
                     'onStateChange' : onPlayerStateChange
                 }
             });*/
            console.log(user);
            setCookie("username", "cookiesValue", 1);
        }else{
            $('#youTubeImage').css({"display":"initial"});
            $('#youTypeLink').css({"display":"none"});
        }

    </script>


</head>
<body>

<div>
    <ul id="youTubeImage" class="thumb">
        <li>
            <div class="overlay">
                <a href="#"><img class="thumbnail" src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/monarch.png" width="192" height="109" alt=""></a>
                <span class="time">3:28</span>
                <a href="#" class="playWrapper" id="myBtn">
                    <!--<span class="playBtn"><img src="http://wptf.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/play-button.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></span>-->
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="thumbCaption"><a href="">This is the description of the video...</a></div>
        </li>          
    </ul>
    <div class="youTypeLink">
        <ul class="thumb">
            <li>
                <div class="overlay">
                    <iframe width="370" height="303" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/OXmIptsCsw0">
                    </iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="thumbCaption"><a href="">This is the description of the video...</a></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Please suggest us to work properly. If cookie have value show video or else showing image.

Comment: **#1** Based on the sensitivity of the data simpy switching between `display:none` and `display:block` is a bad idea from a security perpective.  **#2** Did you try to wrap the conditional in a `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })` ? It could be that your js runs before your DOM is completly rendered therefore the elements you try to manipulate dont exist yet.

Comment: @Lapskaus can you get the answer please?

Comment: Just try putting everthing from `let user = getCookie("username");` to the end of your script block into a `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })`

Comment: @Lapskaus k let me try.

Comment: @Lapskaus working tq.